# How to process lines of standard input interactively in Python?

Tags: python, buffer, stdin

I'd like to use Python as an external process and communicate with it by standard input/standard output.  Specifically, I want to

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    result = compute_something(line)
    print result
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

The output flush is to get the result back right away, without buffering.  I want to do the same with the input--- to process each line right away, without buffering.  However, the above code does not respond to each line individually; it waits until a large amount of data is accumulated in the standard input and then processes everything at once.

This is true *even if* the calling program flushes its standard output with every line.  It's also true *even if* I'm running the above directly on a console.  The buffer is in Python, not the calling program.

Moreover, I found that control-D on the console makes Python flush its standard input buffer.  (And then I can continue to send more input afterward!)  However, that's not useful to me because the calling program can't send the equivalent of control-D at the end of each line.

One more thing: `for line in sys.stdin.xreadlines()` appears to be equivalent to `for line in sys.stdin`: they both buffer.

So my question is, how can I write a Python script that does not buffer its input, so that it processes each line of input right away?

Answer (score 0):

(I solved the problem before posting the question, but I think I should share it anyway--- others might encounter this problem and I'm still interested in any comments on *why* this is happening and what we should all know about how to control Python's or Linux's implicit buffering.)

Here's one way to avoid input buffering:

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    result = compute_something(line)
    print result
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Apparently, `.readline()` avoids the input buffer while direct iteration and `.xreadlines()` do not.